# How to call GetChanges() method from SiteData.asmx web service (SharePoint 2010)?

Tags: web-services

I'm trying to run GetChanges method (sitedata.asmx) from a Java application. However I can't figure out the correct parameters I must pass. This is for SharePoint 2010.

By checking on the [service protocol specification](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/5/8/858F2155-D48D-4C68-9205-29460FD7698F/%5BMS-SITEDATS%5D.PDF), I saw this are the required parameters:

> **objectType:** The change tracking space
> to report about, either
> "ContentDatabase" or "SiteCollection".
> All other objectType values, as
> defined in section 2.2.5.3, MUST NOT
> be used. Note that "Site" in the
> context of this parameter actually
> means site collection.
>
> **contentDatabaseId:** GUID of the content
> database, known in advance or obtained
> by GetContent request.
>
> **LastChangeId:** A token specifying the starting point
> for the requested change report.
> Normally the protocol client obtains
> this value from the response to a
> previous GetContent or GetChanges operation.
>
> **CurrentChangeId:** A token specifying
> the endpoint for the requested change
> report. If not empty, CurrentChangeId
> must be a valid token obtained from
> the response to a previous GetChanges
> operation. Normally, this element is
> empty; empty specifies that the
> protocol client requests all changes
> starting from the starting point up to
> the present time.
>
> **Timeout:** A value
> that determines how many changes
> should be fetched in the current
> operation. This value MUST be greater
> than 0 and the protocol server MUST
> only fetch x% of total changes that
> are fetched by default, where x is
> (Timeout divided by 30000).
>
> The protocol client MUST pass tokens that
> correspond to the change tracking
> space specified by the objectType and
> the target URL of the SOAP request.

The SOAP In message I'm sending is as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns1:GetChanges xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
            <ns1:objectType>SiteCollection</ns1:objectType>
            <ns1:contentDatabaseId>E5C5E20A-5A9F-406C-B9F6-28923750CECD</ns1:contentDatabaseId>
            <ns1:startChangeId>1;0;E5C5E20A-5A9F-406C-B9F6-28923750CECD;634438121498470000;46852</ns1:startChangeId>
            <ns1:Timeout>0</ns1:Timeout>
        </ns1:GetChanges>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

However I get this response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <soap:Code>
                <soap:Value>soap:Receiver</soap:Value>
            </soap:Code>
            <soap:Reason>
                <soap:Text xml:lang="en">Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.</soap:Text>
            </soap:Reason>
            <detail>
                <errorstring xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</errorstring>
            </detail>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Checked the logs from SharePoint (located at Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS) and found the following exception:

```
SOAP exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPChangeToken.ParseChangeToken(String strChangeToken)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPChangeToken..ctor(String strChangeToken)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SiteDataImpl.GetChanges(ObjectType objectType, String contentDatabaseId, String& startChangeId, String& endChangeId, Int64 maxChangesToFetch, UInt32 maxSPRequests, Boolean getMetadata, Boolean ignoreSecurityIfInherit, Int32 schemaVersion, Boolean& moreChanges)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SiteDataImpl.GetChanges(ObjectType objectType, String contentDatabaseId, String& startChangeId, String& endChangeId, Int32 Timeout, Boolean& moreChanges)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SiteData.GetChanges(ObjectType objectType, String contentDatabaseId, String& LastChangeId, String& CurrentChangeId, Int32 Timeout, Boolean& moreChanges)
```

However, I'm not able to find any references to that error. I can't even found the method ParseChangeToken from SPChangeToken class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spchangetoken_methods.aspx), so this is confusing.

I already saw this question, however this doesn't solve my issue: [Other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471028/how-to-use-the-getchanges-method-of-sitedata-webservice)

Can anyone help me calling this web service correctly?

Note: This question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379077/how-to-call-getchanges-method-from-sitedata-asmx-web-service-sharepoint-2010) but I got no responses, So I´m trying here as well.

**EDIT**

Tried calling it from a C# application to determine that the issue is not with Java. This is the code:

```
SiteData.SiteDataSoapClient siteDataService = new SiteData.SiteDataSoapClient();
siteDataService.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("URL/_vti_bin/sitedata.asmx");
siteDataService.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
siteDataService.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;

String startChangeId = "1;1;69d025ce-96a7-4131-adc0-7da1603e8d24;634439002539570000;46914";
String endChangeId = "";
bool hasMoreChanges = false;
String databaseID = E5C5E20A-5A9F-406C-B9F6-28923750CECD; //Got it by querying SharePoint database. Any idea how to get it programatically?
String result = siteDataService.GetChanges(SiteData.ObjectType.SiteCollection, databaseID, ref startChangeId, ref endChangeId, 0, out hasMoreChanges);
return result;
```

However, I got 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' and the detail of this exception is null. Used Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to spy on the XML returned by the SharePoint server, and found the same 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' exception.

So this certainly means there is something wrong with the parameters I'm passing, right?

Thank you!

Comment: Generally we discourage cross-site posting, so once you get an answer we should delete the other one. Perhaps it is a permissions issue? I know that STSADM throws the `NullReferenceException` when you're running a command with an account that doesn't have access to the database.

Comment: Yes, I know it's not a good practice. I'll delete the post that don't get answers as you mention (or reference the answer from the other one, in case both has useful comments). The account I'm using to call the web service is member of the farm administrators group, also it is site collection administrator. On the web application it was granted with Full Control permission. Am I missing something? I guess I granted it with access to everything, it would be great to know exactly what permissions are required though.

Comment: From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774827%28v=office.12%29.aspx), it looks like the account requires "Full Read" permissions.

Comment: Does "Full Control" includes "Full Read"? Well, I tried again granting "Full Read" and got the same result.

Comment: Hmm.. only other thing I can think of is trying it with the service account. If that doesn't work then we might be able to rule out permissions.

Comment: Umm, I think the account I'm using is the service account also. This is running on a developer environment so I didn't bother creating lots of users and permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it. By checking on the SharePoint logs, I noticed the following lines:

```
06/20/2011 08:24:03.80  w3wp.exe (0x1C2C)                           0x0CAC  SharePoint Foundation           General                         fbs6    Medium      <?xml version="1.0" ?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body><GetChanges xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"><objectType>SiteCollection</objectType><contentDatabaseId>{E5C5E20X-5A9F-406C-B9F6-28923750CECD}</contentDatabaseId><startChangeId></startChangeId><endChangeId>1;1;69c025ce-96a7-4131-adc0-7da1603e8d24;634439772069030000;47449</endChangeId><Timeout>0</Timeout></GetChanges></S:Body></S:Envelope>  bafe1d43-e41c-47e9-bff2-5dc35a15298d
06/20/2011 08:24:03.80  w3wp.exe (0x1C2C)                           0x0CAC  SharePoint Foundation           General                         9ka5    Verbose     GetChanges: objectType=SiteCollection, contentDbId={E5C5E20X-5A9F-406C-B9F6-28923750CECD}, startChange=, endChange=; MaxChanges=0, MaxSPRequests=50 bafe1d43-e41c-47e9-bff2-3dc35a15298d
```

Notice on the second line, that the content database Id is enclosed by "{}" characters. Also, see that "contentDbId" is parsed correctly from the incoming XML, while "endChange" is empty. This second observation, is probably what leads to the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception. So, what is wrong with that changeId? No idea, probably there is something wrong with the XML encoding that prevents SharePoint from parsing the changeId correctly.

By further looking on the same log, I found this lines:

```
06/20/2011 08:42:54.35  w3wp.exe (0x1C2C)                           0x2BC4  SharePoint Foundation           General                         fbs6    Medium      <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><ns1:GetChangesEx xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"><ns1:version>1</ns1:version><ns1:xmlInput>&lt;GetChanges>&lt;ObjectType>1&lt;/ObjectType>&lt;ContentDatabaseId>{x4284f47-f050-4fe9-b7e9-caf8f4b882b0}&lt;/ContentDatabaseId>&lt;StartChangeId>1;0;x4284f47-f050-4fe9-b7e9-caf8f4b882b0;634441572386370000;72973&lt;/StartChangeId>&lt;EndChangeId />&lt;RequestLoad>100&lt;/RequestLoad>&lt;GetMetadata>False&lt;/GetMetadata>&lt;IgnoreSecurityIfInherit>True&lt;/IgnoreSecurityIfInherit>&lt;/GetChanges></ns1:xmlInput></ns1:GetChangesEx></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>   fa5ab5a7-2e27-4e78-aa1f-b027ca3b120f
06/20/2011 08:42:54.35  w3wp.exe (0x1C2C)                           0x2BC4  SharePoint Foundation           General                         9ka5    Verbose     GetChanges: objectType=ContentDatabase, contentDbId={x4284f47-f050-4fe9-b7e9-caf8f4b882b0}, startChange=1;0;x4284f47-f050-4fe9-b7e9-caf8f4b882b0;634441572386370000;72973, endChange=; MaxChanges=500, MaxSPRequests=50 fa5ab5b7-2e27-4e78-aa1f-b027ca3b120f
```

Here, the changeId is correctly parsed from the incoming XML. So, I changed from GetChanges() method to GetChangesEx(), passed the exact same parameters I was using on the former call, and it worked correctly!! My guess is that because the parameters are encoded inside an element of the SOAP In request, the Web Service is able to parse them correctly.

Here is the final SOAP In message (formatted):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns1:GetChangesEx xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
            <ns1:version>1</ns1:version>
            <ns1:xmlInput>&lt;GetChanges>&lt;ObjectType>7&lt;/ObjectType>&lt;ContentDatabaseId>{X5C5E20A-5A9F-406C-B9F6-28923750CECD}&lt;/ContentDatabaseId>&lt;StartChangeId>1;1;69f025ce-96a7-4131-adc0-7da1603e8d24;634439727021700000;47404&lt;/StartChangeId>&lt;EndChangeId>1;1;69d025ce-96a7-4131-adc0-7da1603e8b24;634441802456970000;47472&lt;/EndChangeId>&lt;RequestLoad>100&lt;/RequestLoad>&lt;GetMetadata>False&lt;/GetMetadata>&lt;IgnoreSecurityIfInherit>True&lt;/IgnoreSecurityIfInherit>&lt;/GetChanges></ns1:xmlInput>
        </ns1:GetChangesEx>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Edit**

C# code example:

```
SiteData.SiteDataSoapClient siteDataService = new SiteData.SiteDataSoapClient();
siteDataService.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("URL/_vti_bin/sitedata.asmx");
siteDataService.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
siteDataService.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;

String xmlInput = "<GetChanges>" + 
                  "<ObjectType>7</ObjectType>" + 
                  "<ContentDatabaseId>{X5C5E20A-5A9F-406C-B9F6-28923750CECD}</ContentDatabaseId>" + 
                  "<StartChangeId>1;1;69b025ce-96a7-4131-adc0-7da1603e8d24;634439727021700000;47404</StartChangeId>" + 
                  "<EndChangeId>1;1;69b025ce-96a7-4131-adc0-7da1603e8d24;634441802456970000;47472</EndChangeId>" + 
                  "<RequestLoad>100</RequestLoad>" + 
                  "<GetMetadata>False</GetMetadata>" + 
                  "<IgnoreSecurityIfInherit>True</IgnoreSecurityIfInherit>" + 
                  "</GetChanges>";
String result = siteDataService.GetChangesEx(1, xmlInput);
```